# Cisco 1841 to Netgear FVS318 VPN connection

Tags: vpn, cisco, netgear

I've got a site-to-site VPN that was previously between a Cisco 1841 and a Cisco PIX 515. The PIX dropped dead yesterday, and I had to swap in a cheap Netgear firewall to restore basic internet access. I'm hoping to re-establish this tunnel before my replacement Cisco shows up, but the Netgear isn't making it easy.

Let's say the Cisco end is 1.1.1.1 and the Netgear end is 2.2.2.2.

**Here's the relevant config from the Cisco end:**

```
crypto isakmp policy 11
    encr 3des
    authentication pre-share
    group 2
crypto isakmp key redactedKey address 2.2.2.2
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set sharks esp-des esp-md5-hmac
!
crypto map nolan 11 ipsec-isakmp
    set peer 2.2.2.2
    set transform-set sharks
    match address 120
```

**IKE settings entered in Netgear**
Local
Local identity type: WAN IP Address
Local identity data: 2.2.2.2

**Remote**
Remote identntiy type: Remote WAN IP
Remote identity data: [grayed out]

**IKE SA Params**
encryption algo: 3DES
Auth algo: SHA-1
Auth method: PSK: redactedKey
DH group: group 2
SA Life time: 28800

**VPN policy configuration**
Remote address: 1.1.1.1
Local IP: any
Remote IP: range: 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.254 (LAN IP range of remote)
But then there are fields to enter AH and ESP configuration- settings that don't appear to be in the Cisco config. I leave these all blank.

But, when I attempt to apply these settings the NG spits out this unhelpful error:
**ERROR : AH or ESP condition not support**

I don't have any reference to AH or ESP encryption keys in my Cisco config, so I'm not sure what to fill in here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the fields that the NetGear wants that aren't in the Cisco config?  One mismatch in your IKE config to correct - Cisco lifetime defaults to 86400, while the Netgear has 28800.

Comment: Shane: the Netgear wanted to know:
SPI - Incoming _______ (hex, 3-8 chars)
SPI - Outgoing _______ (hex, 3-8 chars)
[ ] Enable Encryption
Encryption algorithm: 
Key - In ________
Key - Out ________

[ ] Enable authentication
Auth algo: 
Key - In: ______
Key - Out: ______

My mistake was not checking the Enable Encryption and Enable Authentication fields. The Netgear GUI lays this out in such a way that you're lead to believe that you must enter keys when selecting these fields. The Cisco config indicates esp-des and esp-md5, so I set Encryption to DES and Auth to MD5.

It's all good now!

Comment: Great!  Once the question's 8 hours old, you can add your own answer to it, which will help future googlers with this same issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was not checking the Enable Encryption and Enable Authentication fields. The Netgear GUI lays this out in such a way that you're lead to believe that you must enter keys when selecting these fields. The Cisco config indicates esp-des and esp-md5, so I set Encryption to DES and Auth to MD5. It's all good now!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the encryption in this manner is set to DES and the Auth to MD5